# How to resolve the jQuery error in the Search Autocomplete module?

Tags: search, ajax

I've just installed the [Search Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) module on my Drupal 7 site and try to get it to work. For this I also installed the jQuery update module and put it on jQuery 1.10. I didn't change any of the default settings of the search autocomplete module. When I start typing in my search field I get this jquery error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null
>   jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js?v=1.10.2:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'label' of null

So I tried finding out what is wrong by setting a breakpoint in the autocomplete jquery file. What I found out is that that on line 474 of this file there is this check:

```
if ( items.length && items[0].label && items[0].value ) {   return items; }
```

But it says that items is [null]. So I went back to views. The automatic generated view made by the autocomplete module outputs this:

```
[
  {
    "link" : "http://site.local:8888/content/elke",
    "value" : "Elke",
    "fields" : {
      "view_node" : "<a href=\"/content/elke\">view</a>",
      "title" : "Elke"
    },
    "group" : {
      "group_id" : "",
      "group_name" : ""
    }
  },
  {
    "link" : "http://site.local:8888/content/peuterdans",
    "value" : "Peuterdans",
    "fields" : {
      "view_node" : "<a href=\"/content/peuterdans\">view</a>",
      "title" : "Peuterdans"
    }
  },
  {
    "link" : "http://site.local:8888/content/sofie",
    "value" : "Sofie",
    "fields" : {
      "view_node" : "<a href=\"/content/sofie-noij\">view</a>",
      "title" : "Sofie"
    }
  }
]
```

So it's not null but is it the right output (following this http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ it is) for the jquery autocomplete? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access, and the purpose of Stack Exchange sites is not guessing.

Comment: Thanks, i tried making it more specific. Anything else I can do?

Comment: You need to figure out where the null value is coming from. Try setting a breakpoint in the js using your browsers developer tools.

Comment: Whow thanks steven I didn't know that fuction yet. I edited my post again. Didn't find the solution yet but it brought me a little further. Something else I can do to get this a step further?